# Disambiguation between franchise and movie tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Slightly related to [Why are there no tags for famous franchises?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/why-are-there-no-tags-for-famous-franchises):

What will we do to distinguish between the tags for a movie and the corresponding franchise/series of movies?

Examples: [batman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman), [saw](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saw), [pirates-of-the-carribean](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirates-of-the-carribean),...

Countless examples could be added, because most franchises have a movie with the same name (usually the first).

It might be helpful to tag movies belonging to a franchise with the corresponding name, to make it easier to find related questions. [avengers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) for example would also include Thor questions, Iron Man questions etc.

But if I only want questions related to the first Batman movie, it would be nice to have the tags separated.

Should we come up with a naming convention for these cases? If so, which?

Maybe a simple [-series] or [-franchise] addition would suffice. What do you guys think?

This problem might not be a pressing matter right now, but the issue will raise sooner or later and it might be good to have a convention in place to prevent inconsistent tagging from the start.

Answer (score 5):

Breakdown of terms:

**Franchise**: the right or license granted by a company to an individual or group to market its products or services in a specific territory.

**Series**: a group or a number of related or similar things, events, etc., arranged or occurring in temporal, spatial, or other order or succession; sequence.

*or*

*Radio and Television:*

- a daily or weekly program with the same cast and format and a continuing story, as a soap opera, situation comedy, or drama.
- a number of related programs having the same theme, cast, or format: a series of four programs on African wildlife.

[Source 1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/franchise)

[Source 2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/series?s=t)

---

From these definitions *Franchise* seems to be improper when talking about a set of movies/tv shows. However, in order to prevent a *clutter*, if you will, of [series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) tags  I think the proper formatting should be as follows:

**IF**  your question is:

- About a plot element across the whole *series* (movie 1, 2, & 3, or season 1, 2, & 3) use a *general* tag:

ex:

- question about jack sparrow in general?  Tag [pirates-of-the-carribean](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirates-of-the-carribean)
- question about what a spell is in Harry Potter?  Tag [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)

---

**IF** your question is

- About a scene or plot element in a title, part of a series, that pertains to **that title only** use a *specific* tag:

ex:

- question about the sword fighting scene in pirates 1?  tag [pirates-of-the-carribean-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirates-of-the-carribean-1) or [curse-of-the-black-pearl](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curse-of-the-black-pearl) If it becomes too cluttered, synonyms are there for a reason.
- question about who died in Deathly Hallows pt2? Tag [harry-potter-8](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-8) or [deathly-hallows-part-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathly-hallows-part-2) or even [deathly-hallows-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathly-hallows-2) are all valid (Again, synonyms will have to be sorted out later)

Comment: I like your proposal. Only issue: I think the common user will rather tag a question about the first movie [pirates-of-the-carribean], while [pirates-of-the-carribean-1] will go unnoticed.

Comment: @atticae aye, that might just have to come down to editing.

Comment: That might work while the questions per day rate is as low as now, but in the end the tagging options should be self-explanatory enough so everyone will know how to tag right away. Anyway, I have no better proposal so I'd say lets do it this way.

Comment: @atticae My only counter is SO which is thousands of time bigger and users still won't know.  It's like bad drivers, no matter how much you take care, how many signs are around etc, there will always be that one guy driving on the wrong side of the road with his blinkers on, hitting the brakes every second :)

Answer (score 3):

I have been meaning to bring this up actually but have not been able to word it properly.

I do agree we need some sort of standardization with franchises in general.

In particular, however, I disagree with your [avengers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) example because each hero has their own franchise and [avengers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) is a cross-over series involving those heroes.  [iron-man](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man) and [thor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor) both have sequels coming up that will be leading into [avengers-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-2) so this example is a bit...special to say the least.

As far as [batman-franchise](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-franchise) or [batman-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-series) I could roll with this if we decide if it should be *franchise* or *series* and what denotes either.

If anyone has a better way to go about this, or some sort of standardization they would like to see, we're all ears :)

Comment: Ok, avengers is a special case, but maybe thats a good example for the difference between franchise and series. I would characterize Avengers as the (overall) franchise and Iron Man as a series within this franchise. (Regarding the avenger franchise see also [TMDb](http://www.themoviedb.org/collection/86311-the-avengers-collection))

Comment: @atticae & TylerShads - I don't have a problem with tagging series or franchises as long as we are consistent.  There is an upper limit to the size of a tag though.  pirates-of-the-carribean-franchise .... might be a bit long.

Comment: @iandotkelly 25-chars I believe

Comment: Is tagging with -s or -f an option, or too obscure?

Comment: @iandotkelly I'd say *way* too obscure

Comment: I am sure we can find a shortened but understandable name for nearly every individual case. [tag:pirates-carribean-series] (24 chars) The main question would be: -series, -franchise or both?

Comment: the issue with batman-franchise is, what constitutes a franchise?  are we saying that batman-franchise will include **all** batman questions (if so then why not just... batman). Or, are we going to distinguish between the Nolan movies and the previous movies?

Comment: And then you start throwing in the animated series and animated movies and....

Comment: @DForck42 I said *new* answer :P

Comment: @tylershads yeah yeah