# why can't we include american pie series as tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

i have seen questions regarding popular movie series like batman,spiderman,etc

why cant we create an famous movie series american pie?

since most of them have already viewed and love the genre of the film

they used to have several doubts when they watch the film,

my suggestion why can't we place an american pie tag?

Comment: Similar to my old question http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/406/why-are-there-no-tags-for-famous-franchises

Answer (score 3):

The tags are there for the questions that are there.

Personally, I think series tags should be reserved when talking about an overarching item, theme, etc of the entire series as a whole as in [this Batman question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/does-christopher-nolans-batman-have-an-overarching-theme), which is a good use of a series tag.

Also discussed [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/disambiguation-between-franchise-and-movie-tags) we are laying groundwork for when to use a franchise tag and when not to use a franchise tag.

One thing users must understand about tags.  If a tag is created and is the only tag for that question as well as the only question with that tag, the system will auto-purge that tag and leave the question with [untagged](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) as the only tag.