# Should new tags distinguish between movies and TV or multiple versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

There were a [couple of questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74200/how-many-disguises-saint-did-in-the-movie) about the 1997 movie [The Saint](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120053/?ref_=nv_sr_3) that showed up on the front page today. I believe this movie was based on the [1960s TV series of the same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055701/?ref_=nv_sr_1). There was no tag for either, so I created one. Now I'm wondering if I should have added a date to it to distinguish it from the TV show (or the [2016 TV movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569088/?ref_=nv_sr_2))?

I'm not sure if my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/disambiguation-between-franchise-and-movie-tags) or not, as it seems mainly concerned with sequels of a movie rather than adaptations to different formats. But if you think it falls under the same scenario, let me know.

Comment: I think tag wiki can do the trick now