# How to tag questions regarding Ghost In The Shell?

Tags: discussion, tags

*Ghost In The Shell* exists as a [Japanese media franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell), and the recently released movie is part of that franchise (because it is a live-action film adaptation of the original *Ghost in the Shell* manga).

I know about ["Disambiguation between franchise and movie tags"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/disambiguation-between-franchise-and-movie-tags), but that doesn't seem to have ended in an agreed upon convention.

It seems users already created a tag specifically for the recent movie: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-2017 . Is this the correct way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I think SF&F had a similar discussion relatively recently (or at least it popped up on their [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/12-monkeys-tag)).

Basically the tag that is created first gets the main (simple) tag rights...in this case [ghost-in-the-shell](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell) anime "wins".

Although this 'first' tag could use its own tag wiki and a disambiguation note. 
[EDIT - Added]

The later movie tag [ghost-in-the-shell-2017](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-2017) with the added designation "2017" after seems fine to me and is perfectly clear.